# Return position of specific element in matrix - R

Tags: r, matrix

I have similarity value matrix (m) as bellow:

```
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]      1.0000000  1.0000000   0.8579698
[2,]      1.0000000  1.0000000   0.8579698
[3,]      0.8579698  0.8579698   1.0000000
```

I would like to get the position of **0.8579698** by easy way . 
I have tried to use  **which** function
it works fine for  element 1.

```
 which( m  == 1.0000000, TRUE)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: For this example, you could also do `which(m) < 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question doesn't say how this matrix has been constructed, but this problem seems to arise from 0.8579698 being the truncated expression of a real (float) value. In general, you can't use exact equality for real values:

```
> .72==.72
[1] TRUE
```

But:

```
> sqrt(.72)
[1] 0.8485281
> sqrt(.72)==0.8485281
[1] FALSE
```

There is a small difference between those apparently equal numbers:

```
> sqrt(.72)-0.8485281
[1] 3.742386e-08
```

A common workaround is to use a difference threshold instead of an equality:

```
> m<-matrix(c(1,1,.72,1,1,.72,.72,.72,1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
> (m<-sqrt(m))
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8485281
[2,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8485281
[3,] 0.8485281 0.8485281 1.0000000
> which(abs(m-.8485)<.0001,arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   3   1
[2,]   3   2
[3,]   1   3
[4,]   2   3
```

Comment: the matrix has been generated from applying euclidean distance on dataset

Comment: Then, I suppose the problem is the same in my example matrix generated using square root. Did the workaround work for you?

Comment: @Noor consider accepting this answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer